# How can I move the p tag's position up instead of it being at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

This is the JSFiddle example. I want to move the p tag so that it is displayed inline at the top, not at the bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    display: inline;
}

p {
    border-bottom: 6px solid red;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 200px;
    font-family: "Arial";
}

p:hover {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>This property is a shorthand property for border-bottom-width, border-bottom-style, and border-bottom-color.</p>

    <p>This property is a shorthand property for border-bottom-width, border-bottom-style, and border-bottom-color.</p>

    <p>This property is a shorthand property for border-bottom-width.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/om7orw9w/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just want to use the `vertical-align` property, set to `top`

```css
div {
 display: inline;
}

p {
    border-bottom: 6px solid red;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 250px;
    font-family: "Arial";
    vertical-align: top;
}

p:hover {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This property is a shorthand property for border-bottom-width, border-bottom-style, and border-bottom-color.</p>
    
  <p>This property is a shorthand property for border-bottom-width, border-bottom-style, and border-bottom-color.</p>
    
  <p>This property is a shorthand property for border-bottom-width.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `vertical-align: top;` for this

```
p {
    border-bottom: 6px solid red;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 250px;
    font-family: "Arial";
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

for updated fiddle demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/om7orw9w/3/)